# Is there something in my VBA code that is causing me to get an overflow error?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm suppose to add up the total volume for each ticker in the stock market. In two columns I need to print each unique ticker and then in the cell right next to it I am suppose to print out the total volume of that ticker. I'm pretty sure most of my code is correct, but when I run it, it only does it once before I get an overflow error.

I've tried resetting my variable that holds the total stock volume a second time, and it stops the overflow error. However, in the Total Stock Volume column is not the total volume of each ticker, but the last volume recorded for each ticker.

```vb
Sub StockVolume()
' Loop through all worksheets

    ' Create the Ticker and Total Stock Volume Columns
        Range("I1") = "Ticker"
        Range("J1") = "Total Stock Volume"

    ' Define a variable to track each ticker that will be pasted in the Ticker column.
        Dim Ticker As String

    ' Define a variable to contain the volume for each ticker
        Dim volume As Long
        volume = 0

    ' Define a variable to count the number of rows
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Keep track of the location for each unique ticker in the summary table
         Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
         Summary_Table_Row = 2

    ' Loop Tickers so that another column displays the unique Tickers
        For i = 2 To lastrow

            ' Condition that tells the program to look for unique tickers to print in the Ticker column
            If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

                ' Stores the unique tickers in the Ticker variable
                Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value

                ' Add to the volume
                 volume = volume + Cells(i, 7).Value

                ' Print the Ticker in the Summary Table
                Range("I" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Ticker

                ' Print the total volume to the Summary Table
                Range("J" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = volume

                ' Add one to the summary table row
                Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1

                ' Reset the total volume
                volume = 0

        ' If the cell immediately following a row is the same ticker...
        Else

            ' Add to the volume
            volume = volume + Cells(i, 7).Value

        End If

  Next i
End Sub
```

I expect to see each unique ticker with its corresponding total stock volume. What I'm getting is the first ticker and its total stock volume and an overflow error message.

Comment: What line throws the error? Also, it might not fix the bug, but using `Option Explicit` and forcing yourself to declare all of your variables would help. Finally, `Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer` should probably be `Dim Summary_Table_Row As Long`. The `Integer` type is not large enough to hold all possible row numbers. Using `Integer` is quite likely the source of your trouble.

Comment: The line that throws the error is the last volume = volume + Cells(i, 7). I believe I have already tried switching my Summary_Table_Row to Long, but I will try again

Comment: I just tried replacing the Integer with Long, but it didn't make a difference. Thank you though.

Comment: What are the values of `volume` and `Cells(i,7)` when the overflow occurs? You need to do some debugging (which we can't do since you didn't provide a [mcve]) to see what is happening.

Comment: I got it to work now by defining my volume variable as Double instead of as Long.

Comment: @ John Coleman, I remember them being ridiculously big. However I just got it to work by defining my volume variable as Double instead of Long. Also I'm sorry if I forgot to add in a bit of information, this was my first question that I posted on here and I'm still getting used to it. Thank you anyways for your help.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. While it is ideal to provide a [mcve] (I encourage you to read that link if you haven't done so already), I realize that in Excel VBA it is unusually difficult since bugs are often due to a combination of code (which you can post) and the state of the spreadsheet (which you can't post, though should try to at least clearly describe).